# How to run startup code in a flask application only for webserver, but not for flask commands?

Tags: python, flask

Here is an example of a simple flask app:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "it works"


@app.cli.command()
def my_cmd():
    print("my-cmd was invoked")


def on_web_server_startup():
    print("run me only in flask or gunicorn webserver")
    print("don't run in me via `flask my-cmd`")
```

I'm trying to organize the code to be able to run `on_web_server_startup` only when the app is started via flask dev server or gunicorn.

But when I run `flask my-cmd` the func `on_web_server_startup` must not be runned.

I know about @before_first_request, but it doesn't a good solutions for me, because my apps can be never requested as a webserver.

I work with the app in three ways:

- I run it in development mode as a webserver via flask dev webserver like this: `export FLASK_APP=app.py flask run`. In this case on_web_server_startup must be executed.
- I run it in production mode as a webserver via gunicorn like this:`gunicorn -b localhost:3000 app:app`. In this case on_web_server_startup must be executed.
- I run different flask commands like this: `flask my-cmd`. In this case on_web_server_startup must NOT be executed.

How can I organize the code to achieve it?

It's possible to archive this by using some env variable. For example, we can run flask dev server and gunicorn with `export SERVER_RUN=1` and than we can check it inside `on_web_server_startup` function.

But is there any other standard way how to distinguish flask webserver from flask commands?